# Различие nano и touch

Tags: linux, bash

В чем ***принципиальное*** различие *nano* и *touch*? Кроме того, что nano - редактор. Или это и есть их ***принципиальное*** различие?

Comment: Ну да, touch не редактирует файл

Answer (score 4):

touch создаёт пустые файлы и обновляет дату редактирования на уже существующих, nano же обычный текстовый редактор